# How to create a non-specific COUNTIF formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I'm looking for a way to be able to make my COUNTIF formula non-specific, e.g. right now I'm placing a 1 next to values that are equal, however in some instances were a value such as 3004785124 is compared against a value which contains the number and should equal a cound (3004785124 // 52-123456) it doesn't work as it is not specifically the value.

Does anyone know a way in which I could fix this problem?

How I want my spreadsheet to look:

```
        A1          A2                      A3
    -----------------------------------------------
    3004785124  3004785124 // 52-237609     1
```

How my spreadsheets currently looking:

```
    A1          A2                            A3
------------------------------------------------------------  
3004785124  3004785124 // 52-237609     0 (=COUNTIF(A1, A2)
```

Comment: I don't understand, please could you make your question a bit clearer? It might help if you included a few more examples.

Comment: Hi @CallumDA I provided an example, pretty much my current formula doesn't count the figure because it also picks up the end of the other figure, but I want it to count it as it contains 3004785124

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks for the example, that made your question a lot clearer.

You can check if one string can be found in another using the `SEARCH` function

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH(A1,A2)),0,1)
```

If `A1` can't be found in `A2` then the `SEARCH` function returns `#VALUE` error, so we just need to deal with that error by wrapping a `ISERROR` function around it.

---

I'll add a little more explanation as per your request.

The search function works as follows and either returns an integer if your string is found or a `#VALUE` error if your string isn't found

```
=SEARCH(find_what, in_what)
=SEARCH("a","abc") 'returns 1
=SEARCH("c","abc") 'returns 3
=SEARCH("d","abc") 'returns #VALUE
```

Carrying on with those examples, `ISERROR(some_value)` will either return `TRUE` if `some_value` is any error, or `FALSE` otherwise

```
=ISERROR(SEARCH("c","abc")) 'returns FALSE
=ISERROR(SEARCH("d","abc")) 'returns TRUE
```

Now it's quite simple,

```
=IF(some_condition, value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

some condition must either be `TRUE` or `FALSE` so that's where we put the previous expressions

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("d","abc")), value_if_true, value_if_false)
```

and because you want `0` when there is an error (i.e. no match) the value_if_true is 0 and value_if_false is 1 where there is no error (i.e. a match)

```
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("d","abc")), 0, 1) 'returns 0 because of error in SEARCH
=IF(ISERROR(SEARCH("c","abc")), 0, 1) 'returns 1 because no error in SEARCH
```

Comment: Hi Callum, I'm glad it made things clearer! - Please let me know if I should share anything else - I'm a bit of a SO noob lol. The formula above didn't seem to work, as if i change the value which is being checked, it still remains 1.

Comment: No problem, welcome to SO! Does this answer your question? If you find this post helpful then please upvote it and if you also found it solved your problem you should mark it as the accepted answer to close off the question (do so by clicking the tick mark on the left)

Comment: Sorry, just edited that comment, forgot when you press enter it auto adds the comments (no enter and space), unfortunately it didn't work as per reasons above.

Comment: Ah, right you are! Sorry about that. SEARCH actually returns a #VALUE error so ISNA won't do the trick. I've updated the answer and tested it works :)

Comment: Ah thank you! This works perfectly! - I kind of don't get the formula though, if you don't mind, would you be able to explain how exactly this formula works?

Comment: Hi @G.Dimitriou, I've updated for more explanation. If there's anything that doesn't make sense just ask away :)